# How can I capture an abstracts class generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm starting to think this isn't possible. I have a generic abstract base class that I wish to keep track of the type of `T`. Only way I found of achieving this is to have a parameter on my base class and re-declaring the generic type in the super constructor.

```
abstract class Base<T> {
  genericType: any;

  constructor(genType: any) {
    this.genericType = genType;
  }
}

class Concrete extends Base<String> {
  constructor() {
    super(String);
  }
}

let obj = new Concrete();
document.write(obj.genericType);
```

What I was hoping to do is simply have something along the lines of this in my base class.

```
genericType: any = T;
```

Comment: Generic constraints only exist in compilation time, javascript has no concept of generics, so in runtime you can not reference `T`. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: It's because I use the generics constructor prototype elsewhere in my code as function arguments.

Comment: You're not making this any clearer. Please add your question and elaborate on what is the problem you're facing and what you're trying to achieve. You cannot use `T` at runtime, but if you explain your scenario maybe you'll get other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `super(String)` you actually passing the constructor function of the String class.

You can rewrite your base class in this way:

```
abstract class Base<T> {
    genericTypeConstructor: {new(): T};

    constructor(genType: {new(): T}) {
        this.genericTypeConstructor = genType;
    }
}
```